# Pydev / eclipse : not recognizing dynamically created class

Tags: python, eclipse, class, dynamic, pydev

In a module Foo I have a function :

```
def register_scheme(class_name,*properties_class):
    scheme_class = type(class_name, (Scheme,), dict( _properties_classes={c.__name__:c for c in properties_class} )) # Scheme is another class defined in Foo
    globals()[class_name] = scheme_class
```

In another module that imports Foo I do:

```
foo.register_scheme("ball",color,distance) # color and distance are two classes defined in this module
```

Now I can do this :

```
ball = foo.ball("color"=red,"distance"=0.5) # __init__ function of Scheme takes care of this, code not shown
```

The code works fine, but pydev complains with a red cross saying "undefined variable from import : ball".

It was to be expected. The issues is that I am going to register a lots of "scheme" in my code, resulting in error messages all over the place. I guess that will not have terrible consequences, but that will be really annoying.

Would anybody have a solution ?

---

EDIT

Here is my solution, which does not correspond exactly to what I wanted, but close enough

```
def register_scheme(class_name,*properties_class):
    #here some code checking if this class name is ok, removed for brevity #
    scheme_class = type(class_name, (Scheme,), dict( _properties_classes={c.__name__:c for c in properties_class} )) 
    Scheme._known_scheme_classes[class_name]=scheme_class # _known_scheme_classes is a class dict of Scheme

def create(scheme_class_name,**values):
    # some code checking such class has been registered, removed for brevity #
    return Scheme._known_scheme_classes[scheme_class_name](**values)
```

Now I can do this in other modules importing foo:

```
foo.register_scheme("ball",color,distance)
my_ball = foo.create("ball",color="red",distance=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a dynamic language, so static code analyzer cannot introspect everything.

In your case it is absolutely normal that PyDev complains that `foo.ball` is an "undefined variable", because it `ball` was not *defined* in the `foo` module, it is *created* at run-time. Eclipse doesn't and cannot know this without actually running the program.

Generally it is bad idea to have this kind of magic.

You have this in your code:

```
globals()[class_name] = scheme_class
```

So you are dynamically creating a class without verifying if it was already created and then inject it into the `globals`.

Then would suggest you instead of injecting it just return it:

```
def crate_scheme(class_name, *properties_class):
    scheme_class = type(class_name, (Scheme,), dict( _properties_classes={c.__name__:c for c in properties_class} )) # Scheme is another class defined in Foo
    return scheme_class
```

Then you would do in another module:

```
Ball = foo.create_scheme("ball", color, distance)  # color and distance are two classes defined in this module
ball = Ball("color"=red, "distance"=0.5)  # __init__ function of Scheme takes care of this, code not shown
```

This should help getting rid of the PyDev complains, but anyway creating classes on the fly should be avoided if possible: explicit is better than implicit (`import this`).

Use composition instead of inheritance here.

Comment: Thanks ! this solution is not really what I need as then Ball exists only for the current package. The idea is to have different modules that can expend the libraries of Schemes ...

Comment: > what I need as then Ball exists only for the current package < My solution does exactly that. When you do `Ball = foo.create_scheme("ball", color, distance)` a variable called `Ball` is created in the current module. If your module is called `bar` then there will appear `bar.Ball` class.